# jQuery validation not validating Spring <form:select>

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, validation, spring-mvc

On one jsp page I'm using bean validation for all `<form:input>` fields, but I couldn't make it work for my `<form:select>`, so just for that I'm using jQuery validation, but for some reason it's not working.

jQuery validation function:

```
$(function() {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter("#submit");
            }
        });
        $("#myForm").validate({
            rules: {
                programSelect: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                programSelect: {
                    required: " Select program!"
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Important parts of jsp page:

```
<c:url var="editUrl" value="/essays/main/student/edit"/>
<form:form modelAttribute="studentAttribute" id="myForm" method="POST" action="${editUrl}">
 <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
 ...
 <form:select path="program" id="programSelect" size="8">
    <form:options items="${programList}" itemValue="programId" itemLabel="programDescription" />            
 </form:select>
 ...
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="edit" id="submit"/>
```

So, I have `id="myForm"` in `<form:form>`, I have all necessary js files linked, I have `id="programSelect"` in `<form:select>`, what am I missing? Can jQuery validation be used just for one element on the page, like in this case? Thank you.

**Update**: generated html has `name` attribute:

```
<select id="programSelect" name="program" size="8">
    <option value="18">First program</option><option value="A2">Fourth program</option><option value="B7">Third program</option><option value="M5">Fourth program</option><option value="M7">Fifth program</option><option value="OA">Sixth program</option>            
 </select>
```

Comment: since `programSelect` is a select the first option will be selected by default... how do you want to make sure that a value is selected in the select box.. is there a value like `Select Program` or something like that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. In my `<form:select>` tag I specified `size="8"`, so first option won't be selected by default. I don't have `<form:option value="0" label="Select Program" />`, if that's what you mean, since it has no place in select box that shows more then one option. I want to make sure that a value is selected in the select box by using jquery validation, which my question is all about. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong @ArunPJohny ?

Comment: can you share the generated html... see whether the name attribute is specified for it

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y8BMp/2/

Comment: I updated my post with generated html @ArunPJohny. I can see that it's working on jsfiddle, so there must be something else on the page that blocks the script...